# Dataset1 - method connection

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have got problem with this method:

```
    public List<int> menu_wid_w_kat()
    {
        DataSet1TableAdapters.menu_widac_wszystkoTableAdapter pk = new DataSet1TableAdapters.menu_widac_wszystkoTableAdapter();
        List<int> lista = new List<int>();
        lista = pk.?
        return lista;
    }
```

In dataset1 I have got Fill, GetData (@id) and this is connected with procedure (procedure working correct)

Problem is in this method because I don't know how connect this method with dataset1 (but I don't want to using linq: `(lista = (from o in pk.GetData() select o.nazwa).ToList();)`)

my idea was but does not work but probably you will understand what I want to do it. Connection with method put (id number) and get data list:

```
lista = pk.GetData(id)
```

I just want to take data from this procedure which exist in dataset1.

[image]
[image]

correct but I can`t find method GetIdList()

baza nasza_baza = new baza();
            var da = new DataSet1TableAdapters.menu_widac_wszystkoTableAdapter();
            List productIDs = da. <- I cant`t find method

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace DataSet1TableAdapters 
{
    public partial class menu_widac_wszystkoTableAdapter
    {
        public List<int> GetIdList(int ids)
        {
            List<int> list = new List<int>();
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand command = this.CommandCollection(ids);
            command.CommandTimeout = command.Connection.ConnectionTimeout;

            System.Data.ConnectionState previousConnectionState = command.Connection.State;
            try
            {
                if (((command.Connection.State & System.Data.ConnectionState.Open) != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open))
                {
                    command.Connection.Open();
                }
                using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        list.Add(reader.GetInt32(0));
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if ((previousConnectionState == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed))
                {
                    command.Connection.Close();
                }
            }

            return list;
        }

        private System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand CommandCollection(int p)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        } 

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fastest approach is to extend the autogenerated `TableAdapter` in your `DataSet` with a method that returns your ID's as `List<int>`.

If you want to extend the functionality you can't change the generated classes in the DatesetName.designer.cs/vb (it will be recreated on any change) but the file without designer in its name(create it if it not exists). Then you have to extend the partial TableAdapter-class(in your case `menu_widac_wszystkoTableAdapter`).

Have a look at following code to see what i mean, i haven't tested it but i hope you take my point:

```
namespace YourRootNameSpace.DataSet1TableAdapters {
{
    public partial class menu_widac_wszystkoTableAdapter
    {
        public List<int> GetIdList(int categoryID)
        {
            List<int> list = new List<int>();
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand command = this.CommandCollection[0];
            command.CommandTimeout = command.Connection.ConnectionTimeout;

            System.Data.ConnectionState previousConnectionState = command.Connection.State;
            try {
                if (((command.Connection.State & System.Data.ConnectionState.Open) != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)) {
                    command.Connection.Open();
                }
                command.Parameters[ "@id" ].Value = categoryID;
                using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader()) {
                    while (reader.Read()) {
                        list.Add(reader.GetInt32(0));
                    }
                }
            } finally {
                if ((previousConnectionState == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)) {
                    command.Connection.Close();
                }
            }

            return list;
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**: After i've read your edited question i saw that i've misunderstood your requirement a little bit, but my approach should be perfect anyway. Basically you don't want to get a `DataTable` but a `List<int>` with your product_ids.

After you've extended the `TableAdapter` in the abovementioned  way:

```
var da = new DataSet1TableAdapters.menu_widac_wszystkoTableAdapter();
List<int> productIDs = da.GetIdList();
```

Comment: check my photos you will understand what I want and I think my problem.

Comment: Then i've misunderstood your requirement but my approach is perfect anyway ;) Basically you have a query and you want a List<int> instead of a DataTable.

Comment: Then you have not extended the TableAdapter in the correct way but created a new class. I assume that it's a namespace issue and you need to include your "root" namespace(see my edited answer). If you are not sure you can always look into the autogenerated `DataSet1.Designer.cs` and search for `menu_widac_wszystkoTableAdapter`. Be sure to use the same namespace to extend the partial class.

Comment: Thx. for help You know I`m just beginner :)

Comment: @RafalPolandBeginner: You're welcome. Note that even the most experienced don't know this DataSet-"secret" since most of them don't use DataSets at all ;)

Comment: Now I have got problem with: error Error 1 The type 'sklep_asp.net.DataSet1TableAdapters.menu_widac_wszystkoTableAdapter' already contains a definition for 'CommandCollection' C:\Users\Rafał\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\sklep_asp.net\sklep_asp.net\menu_widac_wszystkoTableAdapter.cs 43 54 sklep_asp.net

Comment: Error 1 Non-invocable member 'sklep_asp.net.DataSet1TableAdapters.menu_widac_wszystkoTableAdapter.CommandCollection' cannot be used like a method. C:\Users\Rafał\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\sklep_asp.net\sklep_asp.net\menu_widac_wszystkoTableAdapter.cs 14 65 sklep_asp.net

Comment: @RafalPolandBeginner: Sorry, i've converted it from my VB.NET code to C#. `this.CommandCollection(0);` must be `this.CommandCollection[0];` (already corrected above)

Comment: Now I get this: Procedure or function 'menu_widac_wszystko' expects parameter '@id', which was not supplied. What I have to write there to put number for example "2" System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader().?

Comment: @RafalPolandBeginner: Edited accordingly. Since your query needs a parameter("@id"), you need to add this as SqlParameter. I've used the [AddWithValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue.aspx) method to keep it simple. I've also added this a parameter for this method.

Comment: Error: Procedure or function menu_widac_wszystko has too many arguments specified.

Comment: @RafalPolandBeginner: Ah i see, the Command already has this parameter autogenerated(makes sense). So my AddWithValue created another parameter. Then you must replace that line with: `command.Parameters[ "@id" ].Value = categoryID;` (edited above)